# Could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows" -- cx_freeze(.exe)

Tags: python, windows, qt, python-3.6, cx-freeze

I create an .exe file by cx_freeze and copy all the .dll file I can find to the folder which includes that .exe.

The problem is I can run the .exe on my computer perfectly but can't run on another computer by using **the same folder**. I have tried 3 different computers and all pop up the error message "**This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "".**"

It really confuses me why the problem exists on another computer but doesn't exist on mine.

Answer (score 18):

I solved it by copy and paste "platforms" folder to the .exe folder. In my case, because I have installed Anaconda IDE, the path of this folder is Anaconda3/Library/plugins/platforms.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Man I don't know how you don't have more votes. After 3 hours of searching this is what made it work. Thank you!

Comment: see this post: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1270#issuecomment-355741716

Comment: I had this problem with another Qt app and I was sure this was the problem but it did not clear the error message. What I finally realised was that this error would also still be shown until I placed the appropriate Qt5Core.dll, Qt5Gui.dll etc. So you can't solve these errors in the order that they appear... just in case it helps others coming across this post. Otherwise, this was the correct solution for me.

Comment: Saved me! well.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same error and solved it with a different method than those mentioned in other posts. Hopefully this will help future readers.

BUILD:

Windows 10 (64bit) Minicoda (using python 3.9.4) (pkgs are from conda-forge channel) pyqt 5.12.3
VScode 1.56.2

My scenario:

I was building a GUI application for some embedded work. I had two machines that were used for development (same OS and architecture), one had zero internet connection. After packaging up my environment and installing on the offline machine, I ran into the error that you got.

Solution:

locate the qt.conf file in your conda environment. for me: C:\Users"name"\miniconda3\envs"env_name"\qt.conf

Make sure the paths are correct. I needed to update the "name" as this was left over from the old machine.

Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: This didn't solve it for me, but it changed the error message and this was the first post pointing to the `qt.conf` file. It clearly had some paths embedded and was causing some problems. I am also trying to move a conda environment with Qt to another PC that doesn't have internet.

Comment: Yes with a bit more fiddling getting the paths in `qt.conf` set right, now it works, thanks so much!

Comment: Happy to hear it helped, I remember beating my head trying to figure it out.

Comment: Also worked for me, Genius! Thx

(Background: zipped env and unzip to new host. Probably better to use the "pack" command to make sure folders are resolved correctly)