# Problem to load Qt dependencies for python after load Intel oneAPI environment

Tags: python, qt, batch-file, anaconda, intel-oneapi

I'm trying to automate some tasks for my phd research. Basically I have a `.bat` script does the following:

1. Activates the Intel OneAPI environment to compile some C code in order to run some numerical simulations.
2. Compile the C code
3. Execute the `.exe` file
4. call `python` to plot the results of the simulation

However, if the *Intel OneAPI* environment is active, I keep getting this error: `qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "" even though it was found.`

I tried some solutions by including `PyQt` on `windows` `path` but it doesn't work. Here is a sample of the code:

```
@echo off
echo.
echo =====================================================================
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\setvars.bat" intel64
echo =====================================================================

icx /Qstd:c17 /O3 /Ot /Qipo TimeSeries/time_series.c libs/edosystems.c libs/nldyn.c libs/iofiles.c

@ time_series.exe
@ %USERPROFILE%/anaconda3/python.exe -B -m FTimeSeries.out.plot
```

If I do not call the Intel OneAPI environment, I can run python without any problem.

What am I missing here?

Comment: This may be relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/q/44040630/2128947

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's an environment variable issue caused by anaconda3.
Here you will find a possible solution:

> [How to fix "could not find or load the Qt platform plugin windows" while using Matplotlib in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41994485/how-to-fix-could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-windows-while-using-m)